# Is there a way to style PyQt5 application with JavaScript?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm making a desktop application with python and PyQt5, I use qss to style it, and I was wondering if you could use JavaScript to change the style of an element by ID, just like in a website.

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: you may create a form with webview but controls and styling is embedded in PyQt5. here is a working example with PyQt5 https://gist.github.com/mphuie/63e964e9ff8ae25d16a949389392e0d7

Comment: The only thing like this in qss itself is [dynamic properties](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets). However, I don't really see why you need to use javascript for this. If you want to change the style of an element programmatically, just use pyqt.